# If $\rho$ is a representation of $G/K$ then $\rho$ is irreducible if and only if $\tilde\rho$ is.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

> If $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $G/K$ is a group. If $(\rho,V)$ is a
> representation of $G/K$ then, We define the lift (or inflation) $\tilde{\rho}$ of $\rho$ to be the
> homomorphism $G \rightarrow GL(V)$ defined by $\tilde{\rho}(g) = \rho(gK)$ :
> $$\tilde{\rho}
> : G \twoheadrightarrow G/K \xrightarrow{{\rho}} GL(V).$$ If $\rho$ is a representation of $G/K$, then $\tilde{\rho}$ (the inflation of $\rho$) is irreducible if and only if
> $\rho$ is. 
>  Proof. We prove the equivalent statement that $\tilde{\rho}$ is reducible if and only if $\rho$
> is. If $\rho$ is reducible, it has a nonzero proper subrepresentation $W$, then
> so is $\tilde{\rho}$ since $W$ is also a subrepresentation of $\tilde{\rho}$. Conversely, if $\tilde{\rho}$ has a nonzero proper subrepresentation $\sigma$, then $K \subset \ker(\rho) \subset \ker(\sigma)$ and so, by the lemma, $\sigma =\rho_1$ for a representation $\rho_1$ of $G/K$ that is then a nonzero
> proper subrepresentation of $\rho$.

I have two questions. Firstly, how does W being a subrepresentation of $\rho$ imply that it is a subrepresentation of $\tilde{\rho}$? Secondly, why is $K \subset \ker(\rho) \subset \ker(\sigma)$? Why is it not $K \subset \ker(\sigma) \subset \ker(\rho)$?

Comment: I want to complement you on your much-improved MathJax! Also, use `\ker` to make it more upright, i.e. write `$K\subset\ker(\rho)$` rather than `$K\subset$ker$(\rho)$`. There is a general TeX/MathJax "moral" here: do not to exit mathmode when still writing maths. So even writing `$K\subset ker(\rho)$` would be better - exiting mathmode affects line breaks and so on.

Comment: (Things like `\ker` work for other common things, like `\sin` and `\cos`. If you wanted to be pedantic you could make the $GL$ in $GL(V)$ more upright, but there is no automated way of doing it so you need to instead write `$\operatorname{GL}(V)$`, giving $\operatorname{GL}(V)$. Anyway. Keep up the good MathJax-ing.)

Comment: @user1729 Thank you so much! Your comments have certainly been a great help to me. I will continue to take these things on board :)

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that your definition of subrepresentation is just a subspace that is closed under the corresponding action. With this in mind,

first question: if $W$ is a $\rho$-subrepresentation, then $\tilde{\rho}(G)(W)=\rho(G/K)(W)\subseteq W$, so $W$ is also a $\tilde{\rho}$-subrepresentation.

second question:  if $W$ is a $\tilde{\rho}$-subrepresentation and $\sigma: G\to GL(W)$ is the corresponding morphism, then by definition $\sigma$ is the composition
$$G\to GL/K \to GL(V)\to Hom(W,V), $$
where the last arrow is the restriction of linear transformations to the subspace $W$. This is just a fancy way of saying that if it is indeed a subrepresentation, then $K$ acts trivially on $W$, so $K$ must be contained in $\ker(\sigma)$.